# How to static call a Laravel "scope" function?

Tags: function, laravel, search, scope

How can I call two Model Functions in one Function Controller?? 
I'm new on Laravel world, I'm trying to make a Search button, and I have this two functions in my Model.php :

```
public static function Peticion(){
 return DB::table('usados')
    ->join('marcas', 'marcas.id', '=', 'usados.marca_id')
    ->select('usados.*', 'marcas.nombre')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(4);
}

public function scopeSearch($query,$buscar){
return $query->where('modelo', 'LIKE', "%$buscar%");
}
```

and this is my controller.php:

```
public function usados(Request $request) { 
 $usado = Usados::Peticion();
 Usados::Search($request->buscar)->paginate(12);
 return view('usados', compact('usado'));
}
```

My DB structure:

[Table Usados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVQA.png) /// [Table Marcas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04bYu.png)

Both works perfectly but when one works the other doesn't, and I don't know how can I make to they work together in the same controller??

I have the function "Peticion" to list some info from DB, and the other is to a search button..

Comment: is Usados and Search both ur model???

Comment: Both should work you must try sending data to your view as

Comment: @Borna yes, both in the same model

Answer (score 1):

When you declarate the scope in the model then the name of static method call starts from lowercase like this:

```
Usados::search($request->buscar)->paginate(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your model name is model1

then call it from controller like this way

```
$obj=new model1();
$usado=$obj->Peticion();
```

**Edited**

my table called "customers"
[image: customers table]

in controller called **TestController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Http\Requests;
use App\TestModel;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function usados(){

        $obj=new TestModel();
        $usado=$obj->Peticion();
        var_dump($usado);
        $datavar='s';
        echo "search demo here";

        $search=$obj->scopeSearch($datavar);
        var_dump($search);

    }
}
```

in model called **TestModel**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class TestModel extends Model
{
    //
    public static function Peticion(){
        return \DB::table("customers")->select("customers.*")->where("id","<=",11)->get();


    }

    public function scopeSearch($buscar){
     return \DB::table("customers")->select("customers.*")->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$buscar%")->get();

    }
}
```

after vardump
[image]

**Explanation:**
i simply used c++ object concept.
suppose your route is

```
Route::post('/demo','TestController@usados');
```

so it will go TestController's usados function

```
$obj=new TestModel();
```

this line will create a **object** of class **TestModel** called $obj n take address in memory ;
$usado=$obj->Peticion();

here Peticion(); is function .$obj->Peticion(); by this line u called a function Peticion of class **TestModel**.
then it will go to class **TestModel** function called Peticion ,it will return ur query.n come back to controller $usado=$obj->Peticion();
$usado will ur query data.
after var_dump($usado); u can see ur data.
similarly $search=$obj->scopeSearch($datavar);
then u can sent it to ur view

```
return view('viewname',compact('usado','search');
```

hope u understand.

Comment: I can call my functions from model, but only separated. I would like to call to work together in the same controller. Its possible?

Comment: two functions in same method?? yes it works...see my edited answer

Comment: @borma Thanks for your time! I'm new in all of this. Can you explain me better how work this controller? because I can't understand..

Comment: see edited answer .add Explanation in answer.do u apply this concept yet?? or is it work for u? plz let me know.

Comment: So, If I understand you correctly.. I put something like that: 
public function usados(Request $request) { 

    $obj=new Usados();
    $usado=$obj->Peticion();
    // dd(usado);
    $datavar='s';
    $search=$obj->Search($datavar);

    return view('usados', compact('usado', 'search'));
}. 

But the Search doesn't work.. I'm sorry, this is really new for me, and I don't know how to do.. thanks for your time!

Comment: then try to test step by step like first check whether u can go to your controller function or not .public function usados(Request $request) 
{ echo "great test";} then if its ok then try to sent something to modal function like this way public function usados(Request $request) 
{   $obj=new Usados(); $usado=$obj->Peticion(); var_dump($usado);} in modal function   public static function Peticion(){
        $data="data function here";  return $data;
  } ,see what happen .don't use dd use echo or var_dump

Comment: @jhonleg can plz share ur database table structure or colmn names.

Comment: I did the test and apparently its all ok.. Only the scoopeSearch not working when called toghether, only alone If I call alone she work! I think its because they don't can read the function correctly? I edited my question with my DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

Both should work you must try sending data to your view as :

```
public function usados(Request $request) { 
 $usado = Usados::Peticion();
 $search =  Usados::search($request->buscar)->paginate(12);//note s in lower case in search
 return view('usados', compact('usado','search'));
}
```

You should log and debug:

use:   **\Log::info(print_r($usado,true));** //to log an array

Comment: I tried like this but dosen't work.., works only one, the first: "Petición". If I comment this line, the other works too, but not both together.

Comment: alone this line works $search =  Usados::search($request->buscar)->paginate(12); ?

Comment: Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually. refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

Comment: alone works only like this: Usados::search($request->buscar)->paginate(12); I just wanted can call this two functions in the same controller, because one is a search button, and the other list some info from DB! Or maybe a way to make the two functions in one?